# Variable font (width and height)

Tags: opengl, fonts, scale, glut

I'm writing a Level Editor and I'm using the GLUT to display text inside an opengl canvas. However, I would like to scale the text with the canvas instead of staying at the given size (18 at this moment).

How am I able to do this? A friend of mine suggested to create my own font but I think that's a bit much.

This is the code I'm using

> ```
> public void showCharacters(GL gl, String text) {
>   final GLUT glut = new GLUT();
>   System.out.println(text);
>   if (text != null) {
>       gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
>       gl.glRasterPos2f(x + (sizeX / 10), (y - (sizeY)));
>       glut.glutBitmapString(GLUT.BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, text);
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Use `glutStroke*()` and `GLUT_STROKE_*`:

[image: small]

[image: big]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstring>

int glWidth( void* font, const char* str )
{
    int width = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < strlen( str ); ++i )
    {
        width += glutStrokeWidth( font, (int)str[i] );
    }
    return width;
}

void glPrint( void* font, const char* str )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < strlen( str ); ++i )
    {
        glutStrokeCharacter( font, (int)str[i] );
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    glOrtho( -250 * ar, 250 * ar, -250, 250, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    void* font = GLUT_STROKE_MONO_ROMAN;
    const char* str = "Hello";
    glTranslatef( -glWidth( font, str ) / 2.0f, 0, 0 );
    glPrint( font, str );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```